lab.js experiment won't terminate; makes me confirm "leave page?"
When I run my lab.js experiment from within the Builder (i.e., clicking the 'play' button), when I get to the end of the study (and see the "Download Data" banner at the top), it still makes me confirm "leave page?", like the page isn't actually done.  It does usually download the data.  It makes me confirm whether I have the last page set to time out (e.g., times out after 2 seconds) or I set up a specific keystroke response (i.e., "Click the 'c' button to continue").  Relatedly (I think), when I have embedded the program in a Qualtrics page, when it hits the last page of the study and times-out (e.g., after the 2 second wait time I set) the study does not advance to the next part of the Qualtrics survey (i.e., I'm left looking at the last page of my study but can't advance the survey).
In short, it acts like the lab.js study isn't really terminating.  Suggestions are welcome.
I've looked through the lab.js documentation to try to find a way to ensure termination of the study.  I have switched up whether the last time times-out or requires a response, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I've made sure I had it set to either time-out OR require a response to advance.
